# "for your information" or "for your notification"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-request

Which one we should use when we're sending emails to customers to inform them about news or other information?

any other formal or informal suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a native speaker, my preference is "for your information." The other feels stilted, and to me feels like a non-native construction. In fact, if I were reading your message, and I saw "For your notification," I would automatically assume the message was written by a non-native English speaker.

It's worth noting that the phrase "for your information" is sometimes used rhetorically as a defensive statement when one person is trying to respond to criticism, or trying to establish credibility in a defensive way. Consider, "For your information, I DO have a PHD in Warp Field Dynamics, and I have 21 years of experience working with star ship engines." When you hear this, you can tell the person is being defensive, but when you are reading a message, it is harder to tell intent.

So, if I were writing the message, and I wanted to use "For Your Information" as a heading, I think that is fine. If I were wanting to include it in a sentence, I would probably couch it in a less potentially-confrontational way like this: "We wanted to let you know about some changes that have happened..." or "We wanted to inform you about some changes...". This has a friendlier tone than "For your information, we are making changes...".

Answer (score 1):

[*notification*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=notification) by definition implies a notice:

> 1. The act or an instance of notifying.
> 2. Something, such as a letter, by which notice is given.

For example, if you don't pay your electric bill, you will receive a notice/notification that the power will be turned off unless you pay.

Since you are providing information, use **for your information**.
However, *notification* might apply if the information affects the status of products or services already in-process or completed:

> This **notification** was sent to advise you regarding a recall of the item you recently purchased.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase

> For your notification

is not used.  Usually when sending a message which requires immediate attention

> Notice: *something*

is used.

> For your information

is the general phrase used when sending information of interest and may be shortened to

> FYI

in certain circumstances eg texting